# R: Get majority percentage after aggregation with modal function

Tags: raster, r, terra

I want to aggregate a raster using a majority filter (modal) and in addition to that, I want to have a layer in which every cell has the value of the majority percentage. For example: Pixel 1 has a value of 50 after the aggregation. The additional layer should've a value like 90 stating that 90 percent of the aggregated pixels had a value of 50 before the aggregation. Does anyone know how to do this?

I have:

```
library('terra')

set.seed(42)
sample_raster <- terra::rast(ncols=500, nrows=500, xmin = -0, xmax = 50, ymin = 0, ymax = 45, crs = '+init=epsg:4326')
sample_raster <- terra::init(sample_raster, 'chess')
plot(sample_raster)

maj_raster <- terra::aggregate(sample_raster, fact = 10, fun = modal)
plot(maj_raster)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far I know, aggregate's output has the same dimensions than the input file, so from one layer you can't get two layers (app function can handle this). A workaround is creating a custom function for getting the percentage value, then you can stack both layers:

```
custom <- function(x){
  uniq_v <- unique(x)
  output <- uniq_v[which.max(tabulate(match(x, uniq_v)))]
  sum(x == output)/length(x)
}

maj_raster <- terra::aggregate(sample_raster, fact = 10, fun = modal)
perc_raster <- terra::aggregate(sample_raster, fact = 10, fun = custom)
final_raster <- c(maj_raster,perc_raster)
plot(final_raster)
```

[image]

With an example different then chess values:

```
set.seed(123)
sample_raster <- setValues(sample_raster,sample(1:3,size = ncell(sample_raster),replace = T))
maj_raster <- terra::aggregate(sample_raster, fact = 10, fun = modal)
perc_raster <- terra::aggregate(sample_raster, fact = 10, fun = custom)
final_raster <- c(maj_raster,perc_raster)
plot(final_raster)
```

[image]

Comment: This works, thank you! Just a rather small note: I had to change the function slightly to: `custom <- function(x, ...)` in order to handle NA values.

Answer (score 2):

Example data

```
set.seed(42)
sample_raster <- terra::rast(ncols=500, nrows=500, xmin = -0, xmax = 50, ymin = 0, ymax = 45, crs = '+init=epsg:4326')
sample_raster <- (terra::init(sample_raster, runif) * 3) |> round()
```

Solution

```
maj_raster <- terra::aggregate(sample_raster, fact = 10, fun="modal")
a = disagg(maj_raster, 10) |> crop(sample_raster)
b = a == sample_raster
d = aggregate(b, 10, mean, na.rm=TRUE)
```

`d` has the fraction of cells that have the modal value

With `terra 1.5.15` you can now do this in one step by providing a function that returns two numbers

```
fmod <- function(x) {
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  if (length(x) == 0) return(c(NA, NA))
  uv <- unique(x)
  m <- uv[which.max(tabulate(match(x, uv)))]
  c(m, sum(x == m)/length(x))
}

x <- aggregate(sample_raster, fact = 10, fun = fmod)
```

And note that I assumed there might be `NA`s in the data that need to be removed.

Comment: If I apply this to my usecase, I've got the following error executing the line `b = a == sample_raster`: „Error: [==] extents do not match". Is it possible that this results from a rounded aggregation factor?

Comment: Probably because the aggregate raster is larger because the rows or columns are not divisible by factor. The work around is to use `crop`. See updated answer.

Comment: What would be the solution if the aggregation factor needs to be a float value? E.g. Your to be aggregated raster is in NAD83 projection (res = 0.0002777766) but you need it in WGS84 with a resolution of 0.002666667?

Comment: Then you may need a combination of aggregate and resample. In some cases disaggregate and aggregate.